# How to edit an element in a streaming char array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have records coming in from fgets (web data using popen(), not a file) that are in const char * array format.

```
const char * cstr = buff;
```

The 3rd item is a string and needs to either be removed or changed to a zero.
How do I access the 3rd element in a const char * array stream in increments of 5?

```
1
2
string
4
5
1
2
string
4
5
```

code:

```
while(fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fp) != NULL)
{
        const char * cstr2 = buff;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
                if(i == 3){
                        if (!strcmp(cstr2, "Buy\n")) {
                                printf("Found One!\n");
                                cstr2[2] = 0;
                        }
                        if (!strcmp(cstr2, "Sell\n")) {
                                printf("Found Two!\n");
                                cstr2[2] = 0;
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

expected output:

```
1
2
0
4
5
1
2
0
4
5
```

error:
no match and :
error: assignment of read-only location '*(cstr2 + 2u)'

How do you correctly access the 3rd element in a char streaming char array?

Comment: This isn't exactly C++ code if it's littered with `strcmp` calls.

Comment: Your code looks like C, not C++. If you *are* working in / compiling C++, you should be using `std::string` instead of C strings.

Comment: One problem you are going to face is that a `const char * cstr2` is `const` therefore you can't do this: `cstr2[2] = 0;`.

Comment: I don't see your code is making any use of filtered input. Such knowledge is crucial in asnwering your question. First problem (compilation) is caused by 'const' qualifier at cstr2 declaration. More serious problem is that you want to replace third character ??? (cstr2[2]) of your current input line instead of what you specified in question.

Comment: Not 3rd character, but 3rd item. there are 5 items total.

Comment: As cstr2 points onto your current line input buffer, cstr2[2] is third character of your current line. I've made provisional answer, lat me know if it does produce what you've expected.

Comment: Filtered input?  just an array separated by \n  https://bpaste.net/show/5ccf30e6ea75

Comment: I've followed your bpaste, now it is more clear what you need. Answer updated.

Comment: @anonymous your code works, I don't know what happened to your post but if I don't see a repost in a few, I will post it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution was previously posted by anonymous:

```
char* getmyData()
{
    char buff[BUFSIZ];
    FILE *fp = popen("php getMyorders.php 155", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
    size_t size = 1000;
    char* data = (char*)malloc(size);
    char* ptr = data;
    std::string::size_type sz;
    int i=0;
    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp) != NULL)
    {
            const char * cstr2 = buff;
            const char* test = ptr;
            //for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            {
                    if(i == 2){
                            if (!strcmp(cstr2, "Buy\n")) {
                                    printf("Found One!\n");
                                    strcpy(ptr,"0\n");
                                    //ptr+=2;
                            }
                            else
                            if (!strcmp(cstr2, "Sell\n")) {
                                    printf("Found Two!\n");
                                    strcpy(ptr,"0\n");
                                    //ptr+=2;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                strcpy(ptr,cstr2);
                                ptr+=strlen(cstr2);
                            }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strcpy(ptr,cstr2);
                        ptr+=strlen(cstr2);
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        int nc = std::stod (test,&sz);
                        std::cout << "Test: " << 1+nc << "\n";
                    }
                    catch(...)
                    {
                    }

                    i++;
                    if (i==5)
                        i=0;


            }

            if (ptr-data+100>=size)
            {
                int ofs = ptr-data;
                size*=2;
                data = (char*)realloc(data,size);
                ptr = data+ofs;
            }
        }
    return data; // DONT FORGET TO call free() on it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your sample code it is not clear what **is** the expected output. Is it an array of integer ? a formatted text string ? a byte array ? we can't know.

Assuming you have a text formatted input and want a text formatted output, a simple solution is to write a new string with the correct values and not try to modify your input buffer.

If you know the exact format of your input records you could use `fscanf` to do the parsing instead of doing it by hand. And you could use `ssprintf` to do the formatting of the output string.

As others pointed out, if you **can** use C++, you'd have safer/easier options. Please comment about your willingness to use C++.

Comment: The data comes in as text/string but is converted to int for math. See above comments.