# loop error with const char array streaming output, bad output

Tags: c++, arrays

I have data that is coming into my buffer via popen (process data, not a file).
Every seven records is a new set [0-6].
I am trying to print out the array line/element value but my loop appears to be looping through every character and not just every line?

code:

```
char* Data(){

        char buff[BUFSIZ];
        FILE *fp = popen("php order.php 155", "r");
        std::string::size_type sz;
        while(fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fp) != NULL)
        {
                const char * cstr2 = buff;
                for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
                        if(i == 0){
                                std::cout << "value 1: " << cstr2[0] << endl;
                        }
                        if(i == 1){
                                std::cout << "value 2: " << cstr2[1] << endl;
                        }
                        if(i == 2){
                                if (!strcmp(cstr2, "Buy\n")) {
                                        printf("Found String!\n");
                                }
                        }
                }

        }
}
```

existing output:

```
value 1: 1
value 2: 9
value 1: 2
value 2: 0
value 1: B
value 2: u
Found String!
value 1: 0
value 2: .
value 1: 1
value 2: 9
value 1: 1
value 2: 9
value 1: 0
value 2: .
value 1: 1
value 2: 9
value 1: 2
value 2: 0
value 1: B
value 2: u
Found String!
value 1: 0
value 2: .
value 1: 0
value 2: .
value 1: 0
value 2: .
value 1: 0
value 2: .
value 1: 1
value 2: 9
value 1: 2
value 2: 0
value 1: B
value 2: u
Found String!
value 1: 0
value 2: .
value 1: 0
value 2: .
value 1: 0
value 2: .
value 1: 0
value 2: .
value 1: 1
value 2: 9
value 1: 2
value 2: 0
value 1: B
value 2: u
Found String!
value 1: 0
value 2: .
value 1: 0
value 2: .
value 1: 0
value 2: .
value 1: 0
value 2: .
```

expected output:

```
199729173
2014-11-16 10:09:34
Found String!
198397652
2014-11-14 15:10:10
Found String!
198397685
2014-11-14 15:10:13
Found String!
198398295
2014-11-14 15:11:14
Found String!
```

incoming data:
[inbound data](https://bpaste.net/show/04a3434bdbd9)

How do I correct my loop to display the individual lines/elements int the const char array in an if statement similar to the code above??

Comment: Looks like same code as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26996472/how-to-edit-an-element-in-a-streaming-char-array) and [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941563/c-how-to-send-buffer-data-into-an-array-from-popen), but now as three different users?

Comment: I tried to use that code but it doesn't work for me.  :(